# boost property_tree push_back VC2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, boost-propertytree

There have been a number of examples posted to the web that demonstrate how to create a JSON array using boost's property tree.

The basic syntax is:

```
boost::property_tree::ptree array;
array.push_back(std::make_pair("", "value-1"));
array.push_back(std::make_pair("", "value-2"));
```

This appears to not work using boost 1.54 and visual studio c++ 2012. It works fine using VC 2010 and the same boost version.

The error I receive is "cannot convert parameter 1 from std::pair<_Ty1,_Ty2> to const std::pair<_Ty1,_Ty2> &"

Any suggestions that others may have on getting around this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

`ptree::push_back` takes a `ptree::value_type`. Which is not a `pair<key, value>` but a `pair<key, ptree>`. push_back() forwards to insert() which copies the given ptree (defined with pair::second) into the current ptree

I would suggest sticking to `ptree.add()`. See [the five minute tutorial](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/boost_propertytree/tutorial.html), where it does essentially what you're wanting to do with an array of equally named nodes